# Asp.net MVC adicionando nome da aplicação na URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewrite, subdomínio

Tenho um domínio em um servidor compartilhado e dentro dele tenho algumas subpastas que estão setadas como aplicações no IIS 7.
Dentro do domínio principal criei subdomínios que redirecionam para as aplicações/pastas.

**Ex:**

- **www.dominio.com.br**
- **subdominio.dominio.com.br**

Ele funcionava perfeitamente com uma aplicação Asp.net Web Forms.
Porém atualizei a tecnologia para MVC e quando acesso a aplicação pela url **"subdominio.dominio.com.br"** o MVC está adicionando o nome da subpasta/aplicação na url ao clicar em um action link.

**Ex:**

- **subdominio.dominio.com.br/subdominio/Controller/Acction**

e dessa forma a aplicação não funciona.
só funciona se eu acessar o a aplicação pela url: **"www.dominio.host.com.br/App/Controller/Acction"** e mesmo assim teria que mudar alguns requests no código.

gostaria que a url aparece apenas:

- **subdominio.dominio.com.br/Controller/Acction**

Já tentei diversas opções de route no código e também testei URL Rewrite como abaixo mas nada funcionou.

```xml
<system.webServer>
.
.
.
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**Update Sugerido**

```cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Você conferiu se o diretório onde está aplicação MVC está mesmo como aplicação? Se possível atualize sua pergunta com as suas regras de roteamento (RegisterRoutes)

Comment: Sim, o diretório esta como aplicação.
Atualizei, mas esta como padrão do MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimente adicionar a seguinte alteração no "Global.asax".

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "subdominio_1",
            "Subdominio/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //Mantenha as outras rotas
    }
```

Comment: obrigado, dessa forma fica do jeito que eu queria evitar, mas acabei deixando com o nome da aplicação no final mesmo, não tem jeito, por ser servidor compartilhado as regras de reescrita da própria hospedagem não permitem que apareça sem o nome da pasta, acabei fazendo os ajustes manuais no projeto para não ter problemas com erros do tipo "404"... mas obrigado!