# Criar site de notícias dinâmico otimizado para o Google

Tags: google

Quero criar páginas em um site específico de notícias e pensei inicialmente em armazenar em um banco de dados as informações de notícias (título, assunto, texto da notícia, etc). Assim que minha página `noticia.aspx` fosse acessada, buscaria o conteúdo da notícia no banco de dados.

Mas essa não é uma boa prática para os motores de busca do Google encontrar minha página. Notei também que sites como Uol, Globo.com apresentam a página de notícia com a extensão "HTML",conforme exemplo abaixo:

> http://g1.globo.com/economia/mercados/noticia/2015/09/cotacao-do-dolar-250915.html

Como esses sites gerenciam essas notícias? Eles geram páginas estáticas?
Qual a forma de gerar esse conteúdo de forma dinâmica e que seja visivel para o Google?

Comment: Que tecnologia está usando no seu site?

Comment: @bigown estou usando MVC asp.net (C#)

Comment: Dê uma olhada no tour. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

De onde tirou a informação que essa não é um boa prática? Não existe problema algum em fazer isso. Todos os sites fazem, o mecanismo de busca acessa a página como se fosse um navegador.

## Como funciona a geração de página

Só não digo "se o navegador vê o conteúdo o mecanismo de busca também verá" porque isto não é uma verdade absoluta quando o conteúdo é montado através de JavaScript.

Há o mito que hoje isto está solucionado, mas não não é verdade. A situação que era zero capacidade dos mecanismos entenderem JS, melhorou, mas ainda tem chão. E mesmo assim tem técnicas próprias para conseguir um resultado razoável em alguns mecanismos, não todos. Se bem que só o Google conta de verdade.

Qualquer página gerada *on-the-fly* no servidor será vista normalmente sem qualquer problema. A única razão para gerar páginas estáticas seria otimizar a capacidade do servidor já que você geraria uma página uma vez e depois só faria acessos. Mas já vi gente abusar disto e obter o resultado contrário.

Quando a página é dinâmica ela é gerada todas as vezes que for solicitada, a não ser que se faça uso de cache. E obviamente o cache geral de página só funciona se a página nunca muda, ou pelo menos muda pouco, o que não é tão comum. É frequente cada página requisitada ter uma diferença para a anterior, por publicidade, novidades, personalização ou outro motivo. Páginas dinâmicas geram mais carga no servidor, mas na maioria dos casos isto não é problema, e os vários níveis de cache ajudarão a mitigar uma carga muito intensa.

O cache do navegador também é seu amigo.

O problema está nessas páginas [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Neste caso a geração é feita no navegador, pelo JS. O mecanismo de busca pode simular algumas execuções e gerar o conteúdo, mas há vários situações que isto é impraticável.

## Extensão do nome da página

Quando você gera uma página pode por a extensão que quiser. Não é obrigatório que seja `.aspx`, ou `.php` ou outra extensão para ela ser processada.

Se você configurar o servidor HTTP para uma extensão ser processada, toda vez que algo com esta extensão configurada for chamada acionará um processador designado, que pode ser uma aplicação ou interpretador de uma linguagem. Pode configurar para o `.html` ser processado como uma aplicação ASP.NET se quiser. Se convencionou que a extensão `.html` é usada para páginas estáticas, mas nada impede que não seja isto.

## URL amigável

Além disto é possível usar um [URL amigável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128341/101) ([outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21943/101)) que transforma o URL em uma rota que internamente no servidor chama alguma aplicação ou pedaço dela em específico. Ou seja, você disfarça o endereço real da aplicação para algo que fique mais fácil das pessoas lerem, e os mecanismos de busca identificarem o conteúdo. Esta é uma técnica muito comum que pode ser [configurada no servidor HTTP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1326/101) (Apache, IIS, etc.) ou [dentro da aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2289/101). Particularmente prefiro dentro da aplicação.

## Conclusão

Não se preocupe em gerar páginas dinâmicas. E quando isto estiver criando problemas de carga, comece ver técnicas para reduzir o problema, mas não antes.

Estas são informações gerais. Quando tiver dúvidas mais específicas abra perguntas mais específicas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

> A resposta do @Maniero responde toda a parte teórica por trás, eu apenas irei adicionar uma parte prática de como fazer isso em [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), já que o AP disse que é o que [ele está usando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89083/criar-site-de-not%C3%ADcias-din%C3%A2mico-otimizado-para-o-google/89221#comment183242_89083).

Para adicionar a extensão `.html` em suas páginas não é necessário criar páginas estáticas, basta utilizar o mecanismo de rotas do `Asp.NET MVC` para isso.

Por exemplo, se está buscando uma notícia, basta fazer isso em seu controller:

```
[Route("{categoria}/noticia/{ano}/{mes}/{titulo}.html")]
public ActionResult Detalhes(string ano, string mes, string titulo)
{
    var noticia = db.Noticias.FirstOrDefatul(´/*where aqui*/);

    return View(noticia);
}
```

E em seu arquivo `Web.config` adcione esta linha:

```
<system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Feito isso, estará gerando `URL's` com a extensão `.html`, mas sem ter páginas estáticas, como no exemplo citado na pergunta.

> http://g1.globo.com/economia/mercados/noticia/2015/09/cotacao-do-dolar-250915.html