# O que são URLs amigáveis?

Tags: aplicação-web, url, terminologia, url-amigável

- O que são URLs amigáveis?
- Qual sua finalidade?
- Quando se é recomendado utilizar URLs amigáveis ao invés de URLs normais?
- Envolve alguma relação com desempenho?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Definição

São [URLs ou URIs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/101) mais fáceis de ler. Elas adotam a estrutura de pastas comumente usada para indicar sobre o conteúdo, incluindo aí os parâmetros usados para chegar naquele conteúdo específico.

É o oposto do acesso normal de conteúdo parametrizado que usa mecanismos próprios de passagem do parâmetro, em geral trabalhando com códigos identificadores. O URL fica mais "sujo" e não identifica o conteúdo.

## Finalidade

Tem várias finalidades.

#### Abstração

Essa técnica esconde os detalhes de implementação e normaliza o jeito de acessar. Como é comum usar uma técnica de REST fica mais fácil o usuário mais técnico adaptar o URL para acessar um outro conteúdo que deseja. Isso não é tão fácil assim também. Os usuários mais experientes deste site em maior ou menor grau sabem fazer isso, mas quase a totalidade dos outros usuários não sabem, e olhe que são usuários bem técnicos.

É uma técnica de **abstração**. Se a implementação real nunca for exposta para os usuários, o desenvolvedor pode trocar a forma interna de manipular os URLs sem afetar o funcionamento exterior do site. Esse provavelmente é o motivo mais importante dessa técnica. O resto é secundário.

#### Segurança

Pode haver ganhos de segurança fazendo isso. Mas não só pelo fato de aplicar a técnica está tudo seguro, precisa de outras em conjunto.

#### Encurtamento, redirecionamento e normalização

Isso é feito com uma técnica de [redirecionamento de URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) no servidor web ou na própria aplicação (o que muita gente não sabe, e que pode dar mais controle).

Muitas vezes é usado para [encurtar o URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening).

Outras vezes é uma forma de [normalizar o endereço](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) de forma consistente.

Outra técnica é a persistência de endereço usando [PURL (Persistent uniform resource locator)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_uniform_resource_locator).

#### Semântica e legibilidade

No fundo é um [URL que possui mais semântica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL). E aí o URL pode ficar até maior.

URL amigável é mais fácil de ler pelo humano que identifica melhor o que tem ali. Em geral ela descreve o conteúdo com palavras em oposição, ou com adição, de um código de acesso.

Olha aí em cima no seu navegador agora. Tem um URL amigável. Tem o ID da pergunta e o título dela de forma simplificada. Você pode bater o olho ali e saber do que se trata esta aba do navegador sem ver o conteúdo dela.

Pode ajudar de diversas formas, incluindo ter uma noção do que se trata antes de clicar quando ele recebe o URL de algum lugar. Quando tem no *bookmark* dele, incluindo aí o autocompletar do navegador.

Obviamente que se o usuário for obrigado digitar todo URL semântico pode se tornar um fardo. E tem sites que obrigam isso. Outras tornam a forma mais curta opcional.

Fica mais fácil identificar conteúdo em *logs* de acesso.

Bem mais fácil, não?

#### Slug

Essa porção descritiva citada acima normalmente é chamada de *slug*.

Mas tem que tomar um pouco de cuidado porque o título (ou outra informação que seja usada para dar mais semântica) não é uma informação estável. Tem que usar técnicas para a situação de troca do conteúdo e manter o acesso aos antigos ativos consistente.

#### SEO

Também pode ajudar SEO também. Ele dá uma informação extra para os mecanismos de busca indexarem o conteúdo. Não que ajude tanto.

## Quando usar

Tem que usar quando domina o assunto. Como tudo, se for para fazer besteira, não faça. Vá no arroz com feijão que ganha mais.

Não espere uma revolução por usar. Em geral os programadores usam porque todo mundo usa, porque ouviram falar que é bom ou porque acham bonitinho. Claro que existe alguma vantagem, mas a maioria não sabe porque. E o porquê pode variar de acordo com o tipo de projeto.

Fora isso o uso deve ser quando precisa facilitar o acesso e abstrair o real endereço do recurso a ser acessado.

Como tudo, há vantagens e desvantagens. Vejo muito site que não usa a técnica correta e tem mais problemas do que soluções, ou seja criam URLs ainda menos amigáveis.

## Performance

A performance delas costuma ser ligeiramente pior, afinal precisa fazer uma conversão para o URL "correto", mas imperceptível de fato, é uma diferença irrelevante na maioria dos casos.

Exemplos:

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=consulting/marketing => http://example.com/consulting/marketing
http://example.com/products?category=2&pid=25 => http://example.com/products/2/25
http://pt.stackoverflow.com?qid=128341 => https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128341/o-que-são-urls-amigáveis
```

[Artigo interessante sobre o assunto](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI). Se todo mundo lesse, faria bem menos barbeiragem com isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No meu caso a principal finalidade é fazer algo do tipo: `http://example.com/profile.php?user=bigown` para `http://example.com/profile/bigown/`. Acha que para isto é bom o uso de URL's amigáveis?

Comment: Em geral, sim..

Answer (score 14):

Um url amigável é aquele que é perceptivel por humanos e contem uma descrição do conteúdo que serve.

Um url não amigavel seria assim, por exemplo:

```
meusite.com/23376453
```

Um url amigável seria

```
meusite.com/receitas-de-cozinha-japonesa
```

Ora ambos podem servir o mesmo conteúdo, contudo o segundo exemplo é mais semântico, melhor em termos de SEO pois tem palavras importantes para descrever o conteúdo; e perceptivel para humanos. Em quanto que o primeiro exemplo não me diz nada, e nem me permite adivinhar nada sobre o sue conteúdo.

O url não amigavel foi comum no inicio da web, no inicio dos CMS, onde o conteúdo era gerênciado por uma base de dados e cada página ficava com uma ID, ID essa usada no url. Hoje em dia dá-se muita importância, pelas razões já descritas à legibilidade.

Em termos de performance é indiferente. Em relação à pergunta *"Quando se é recomendado utilizar URLs amigáveis ao ínves de URLs normais?"* eu diria que urls amigáveis **são** urls normais. Só em casos específicos de numeros de produto ou aplicações offline é que uso urls numéricos, não amigáveis.

Answer (score 2):

## O que é URL amigável?

A URL amigável é uma URL mais fácil de compreender, tanto para os mecanismos de busca quanto para quem acessa o seu site.

Para uma URL ser amigável, devemos entender do que a página se trata assim que olhamos para ela.

Este seria um exemplo de uma boa URL:

resultadosdigitais.com.br/trabalhe-conosco/

Já esta não deixa claro sobre o que a página trata, passando uma ideia pouco profissional. O mais provável é que acabe repelindo o usuário:

resultadosdigitais.com.br/j4378478fhx/

## Por que a URL amigável é importante?

Assim como um site poderia ser acessado pelo seu endereço de IP e o domínio o ajuda a ser mais comercial e amigável para o usuário, creio que as URLs amigáveis ajudem o usuário a compreender melhor a página que estão acessando e assim sintam-se mais confiantes em relação ao conteúdo apresentado, bem como a realizar uma compra.

Isso não vale para todos os usuários, pois muitos deles não costumam dar importância para a URL. Mas muitos se importam sim.

Veja alguns exemplos de URLs amigáveis:

http://www.dominio.com/diretorio/nome-do-arquivo.html

http://www.dominio.com/nome-do-arquivo.html

http://www.dominio.com/diretorio/nome-da-pagina/

http://www.dominio.com/nome-da-pagina/

http://www.dominio.com/diretorio/sub-diretorio/nome-da-pagina/

etc.

## Grande vantagem em usar URL Amigável?

A Grande vantagem das URLs amigáveis é que elas ajudam a evitar o famigerado e temido conteúdo duplicado, que pode reduzir em muito o potencial de um site, porque o robô do Google em vez de indexar e atualizar as páginas devidas, fica indexando páginas dinâmicas que no fundo são iguais a todas as outras.

Isso acontece porque muitos sites dinâmicos costumam adicionar um parâmetro (ex.: &filtro-genero=masculino) às URLs existentes, mesmo que a URL já tenha esse filtro e o robô do Google as indexa, porque não entende que essas URLs não são no fundo a mesma página.

Você pode evitar o conteúdo duplicado implementando a [canonical tag](https://marketingdeconteudo.com/canonical-tag/).

Comment: Muito claro sua resposta

Comment: Busque referenciar o conteúdo que você utiliza nas suas respostas: [O que é uma URL amigável para o Google e outros buscadores](https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/url-amigavel/). Só lembrando que copiar/colar, mesmo colocando a fonte, ainda é considerado plágio. Tome muito cuidado. Aliás, desta página que copiou o conteúdo, você verificou se possui direito de cópia?

Comment: Fonte: https://resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/url-amigavel/, https://www.conversion.com.br/blog/urls-amigaveis-estaticas-dinamicas-curtas-e-encurtadores/, https://marketingdeconteudo.com/canonical-tag/