# Organizar site por pastas no diretório

Tags: php, htaccess

Estou me aventurando no meu primeiro site escrito em PHP e tem uma coisa me incomodando, que é o jeito que fica a URL do site, por exemplo:

```
meusite.com/index.php?page=ucp&p=edit&id=58
```

A URL fica enorme, eu gostaria de saber qual o melhor jeito de organizar o site por diretório em pastas, exemplo:

```
meusite.com/ucp/
```

Atualmente eu uso apenas uma index chamando a função include que leva para a pasta onde estão as páginas.

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Veja aqui como usar htacess: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis-com-regras-complexas

Comment: O recomendaria a ver algum framework php para facilitar sua vida. Recomendaria Codeigniter. Uma mão na roda. Porém, como você disse que está começando, saber programar na linguagem pura é importante também. htaccess é uma solução para seu problema.

Comment: Só adicionando uma informação relevante... para a utilização do .htacess, é necessário ter ativado o mod_rewrite no seu servidor.

Comment: A estrutura do código-fonte poucas vezes é a mais conveniente para organizar a URL. Se você não precisar de um framework, uma [biblioteca que faça o URL routing](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router) pode ser útil. Recomendo contra usar .htacess porque cria dependência no servidor HTTP que você tá usando, se quiser mudar pro nginx depois vai dar trabalho.

Comment: Se for o que eu estou pensando é bastante simples. Você só precisa criar uma pasta com o nome que deseja e por o arquivo `index.php` dentro. Se for apenas organizar a URL, ai você pode estar utilizando URL's amigáveis.

Comment: Alguma das respostas ajudaram?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que devo ter entendido a sua questão é muito simples mesmo.

Caso você queira apenas organizar a URL e os arquivos em questão, você pode simplesmente criar uma pasta, por exemplo, chamada `ucp` e por o `index.php` dentro dela e então acessar. `meusite.com/ucp`.

Mas se o que você deseja é apenas organizar a URL e não mexer no resto, você pode estar utilizando URLs amigáveis. [O que são URLs amigáveis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128341/o-que-s%C3%A3o-urls-amig%C3%A1veis)
Também tem esse tutorial, que ensina como criar uma URL amigável: [Clique aqui](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/criando-url-amigaveis-com-um-codigo-simples-e-funcional)

Se seu problema é informações da página que queira que tenha em todas e por isto está incluindo a página através do *include*, você pode fazer exatamente isto. Cria um arquivo com as informações que você deseja repetir e então inclua em todos que você deseja.

Comment: então pelo que entendi em cada pagina eu coloco uma pagina index junto ?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, companheiro. Nesse caso, constaria você usar URL's Amigáveis com o .htaccess, como mencionado em diversos comentários de nossos companheiros.
No seu caso você deve passar os parâmetros para a URL e assim vai abrir o arquivo com os parâmetros de acordo.
Aqui vai um exemplo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z])/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9])$ index.php?page=$1&p=$2&id=$3 [QSA]
```

Nesse caso:

**RewriteEngine on:** Imprescindível para a criação de suas URL's amigáveis. Coloque isso acima de onde você irá especificar suas regras. **RewriteRule:** indica o início de sua regra. **^([a-zA-Z])/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])/([0-9])$** indica com expressões regulares o formato da URL que cairá nessa regra, no caso, a URL deverá iniciar com algum *valor de a até z maiúsculo ou minúsculo **/** valor de a até z maiúsculo ou minúsculo ou números, assim como "_" e "-" **/** valor numérico*. Ao final, **index.php?page=$1&p=$2&id=$3 [QSA]** indica qual URL ele acessará através dessa regra, especificando com *$1, $2 e $3* as expressões regulares em seus devidos parâmetros. *[QSA]* deve constar ao final, para especificar que sua regra contém uma string para consulta ("Query String Append"), no caso, nossos parâmetros.

Utilizando essa regra que citei, *http://www.seusite.com/ucp/edit/58* seria a mesma coisa de acessar *http://www.seusite.com/index.php?page=ucp&p=edit&id=58*.

Importante: Esteja certo de que o mod rewrite do apache esteja ativado.