# Mascarar caminho da url em servidor IIS

Tags: url, iis, web.config

Estou com uma dúvida na qual eu preciso mas mostrar um caminho na url que seja mais amigável para o usuário, como esse:

http://hexatasistemas.com.br/sites/mercedita/efetuarlogin.asp

Queria que ao invés de mostrar todo esse caminho mostrasse apenas

http://hexatasistemas.com.br/mercedita/

Assim como nesse [site](http://mercedita.com.br/) ao clicar em algum link no menu.

**Obs:** Meu servidor é Windows com IIS, e não funciona o `.htaccess` nem o `mod_rewrite` que são pra `Apache`. Agradeço desde já, e caso não tenham entendido ou tenha alguma dúvida é só comentar.

Comment: **Relacionada**: [O que são URLs amigáveis?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128341/4808)

Comment: Isso pode ser resolvido com uma estrutura de rotas, que poderá ser feita de várias maneiras, dependendo das tecnologias que vc está usando.

Comment: Estou programando esse site em asp. Vi algo sobre um arquivo .htaccess mas não consegui entender nada.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como posso simplificar os URLs para um site?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326/como-posso-simplificar-os-urls-para-um-site)

Comment: Wallace, esse seu link trabalha com apache e não funciona no meu pois é IIS. Vou editar minha pergunta especificando isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando htaccess é possível fazer

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^mercedita/?$ /sites/mercedita/efetuarlogin.asp [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Dessa forma quando existir /mercedita após o .com.br o servidor irá entender que é a mesma coisa que /sites/mercedita/efetuarlogin.asp

Aqui você vai poder entender um pouco melhor sobre o funcionamento
http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis

Para ASP IIS adicionar o seguinte código no seu `web.config` dentro da tag `<system.webServer>`:

```
<rewrite> 
  <rules> 
    <rule name="renomelogin" stopProcessing="true"> 
      <match url="^mercedita$" ignoreCase="true" /> 
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
      </conditions> 
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/sites/mercedita/efetuarlogin.asp" appendQueryString="true" /> 
    </rule> 
  </rules> 
</rewrite>
```

Obs: Se a pessoa digitar mercedita/ a pagina não será encontrada, para isso você deve adicionar mais uma regra(`<rule>`) com um nome diferente e alterar a linha

```
    <rule name="renome login com barra" stopProcessing="true"> 
      <match url="^mercedita/$" ignoreCase="true" /> // Adicione a barra no final
```

Comment: asp é normalmente sob IIS.. htaccess é do apache

Comment: Vi o comentário dele dizendo que não conseguiu usar htaccess e dei um exemplo, mas obrigado, não sabia que htaccess não funciona com asp, sempre usei em php / apache

Comment: Na raíz do meu servidor encontrei um arquivo `web.config` será que dá pra usá-lo?

Comment: Como está usando Asp da uma lida nesse tutorial e vê se lhe ajuda, http://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-e-exemplo-url-amigaveis-em-asp-net/23270

Comment: Não funcionou @Leo. O meu é asp classico e esse é asp.Net

Comment: Esse tutorial ensina a fazer pelo web.config, da uma olhada http://www.rafaelwendel.com/2011/10/url-amigaveis-no-iis/ @BrunoRomualdo

Comment: Já havia dado uma uma olhada nesse site mas não consegui entender onde alterar para aplicar no meu exemplo. Teria como alterar sua resposta com um exemplo?

Comment: Adicionei o código, testa ai se funciona, não entendo sobre ASP

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49448/discussion-between-bruno-romualdo-and-leo-letto).