# Não aparecer arquivo na barra de enredeço

Tags: php, htaccess

Como faço para aparecer só a pasta na barra de endereço, por ex:

> www.teste.com.br/admin

Ao vez de aparecer assim:

> www.teste.com.br/admin/index.php

Comment: Isso se chama URL Amigável e é configurada pelo arquivo .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Ative o `mod_rewrite` no Apache, geralmente já vem ativado.

Use o seguinte comando:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Na `RewriteRule` você diz ao servidor que quando a URL www.seudominio.com/admin for acessada a mesma deve ser interpretada como www.seudominio.com/admin/index.php

Aqui a mesma pergunta com `htaccess` e IIS
[Mascarar caminho da url em servidor IIS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169024/mascarar-caminho-da-url-em-servidor-iis/169027#169027)

Você pode encontrar mais exemplo complexos sobre o funcionamento das URL's amigáveis http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis-com-regras-complexas

Comment: Favoreça as respostas existentes, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=remover+index