# Ajax com url limpa como usar o voltar do navegador

Tags: ajax, url

Olá,

Alguém sabe como posso usar o voltar do navegador com algum recurso ajax/jquery, considerando que a url está limpa?

- Por exemplo, ao navegar cria-se uma sessão php, dessa forma quando navego entre a pagina1, pagina2 e 3, a url continua limpa, ex: http://sistema.com.br/
- Quando estou na pagina2, quero usar o voltar do navegador, retornado para1, e continuar com a url limpa...

Comment: Quando você diz: **"navegar entre as paginas 1,2 e 3"** esta querendo dizer que busca estas páginas "dinamicamente"? Se for isto, não havendo histórico de navegação no site não há como voltar...afinal de contas para onde voltaria já que não foi a lugar algum?

Comment: Busco de forma dinamica, e crio uma sessão no navegador, então me refiro em utilizar essa sessão para atribuir ao voltar.

Comment: Como você vai usar a sessão para voltar? Quando fala sessão, que tipo em que linguagem exatamente (PHP?)?

Comment: Sim, com php. Digamos que guardo uma string na sessão, como  'pagina1', então gostaria de saber algum comando com jquery, para que possa fazer o .load() da pagina, ao executar o voltar do navegador, com essa string.

Comment: Ok, entendi. Más, raciocine comigo: se não foi feita navegação para lugar algum no domínio, logo o botão voltar não irá funcionar ao seu propósito. O jeito seria adicionar ao histórico por exemplo: ao fazer `.load('pagina1.html')` adicionar ao histórico `pagina1.html` e assim para os demais carregamentos...assim o botão voltar funciona más, a url muda.

Comment: Você pode armazenar as views como biscoitos.

Comment: mesmo q salva-se a página que ele esta buscando em cookies, como ele poderia usar o botão voltar se não tiver nada no histórico?

Comment: Precisaria de algum comando com jquery, que referenciasse essa string da sessão na hora de voltar.. como .pushState().. algo assim, mas não sei qual.. existe o .session() do jquery tbm.. gostaria de saber como implementar, e como chamar a função do voltar

Comment: Atila Silva, qual sua idéia?

Comment: Lauro, com relação ao histórico, deve haver uma forma de cria-lo de forma dinamica..

Comment: Manter a URL limpa é provavelmente uma péssima experiencia para o usuário, afinal o intuito das URLs é tornar intuitivo aonde se localiza e fazer o uso do histórico e bookmakers (favoritos).

Comment: Só pra constar, não tem como manipular o histórico dinamicamente, ele é baseado nas URLs, a unica coisa que vai conseguir com pushState para manter a url limpa é ter na aba atual o back e next das paginações, se pudesse alterar o histórico diretamente seria uma grave falha de segurança em relação a privacidade do usuário.

Comment: Guilherme, considerando um sistema, existem breadcrumbs para a experiencia do usuario intuitiva em relação a sua navegação. O codigo de @Tobias logo abaixo parece chegar bem proximo do que é preciso.

Comment: Tanto historico quanto favoritos dependem de URLs próprias para cada item que deseja apresentar, até mesmo para google isto é um requisito, URLs canônicas de preferencia. Retirar este recurso do usuário, sendo um site normal é um grande problema, tanto para indexação quanto pro usuário em relação ao uso das ferramentas do navegador, isto também complicaria em sistemas de feed, pois não teriam URLs para apontar. Sendo sincero, isto me parece apenas um recurso estético, sem necessidade alguma, eu lhe aconselharia a criar URL amigáveis: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128341/3635

Comment: @Guilherme, seu pensamento está voltado a um site, quando na verdade estou referenciando um sistema. São necessidades distintas.

Comment: @Neo isto não era tão óbvio, mas sendo um sistema fechado não seria mais interessante criar um APP que tornasse as URLs menos evidentes, algo como [Electronjs](https://electronjs.org)?

Comment: @Guilherme, vou ver o Electronjs, como funciona, ferramenta interessante. Mas como tenho outra forma de desenvolver atualmente que atende bem, preciso implementar algumas coisas especificas.

Comment: @Neo além do `ElectronJS` citado pelo @GuilhermeNascimento, você também pode estudar um pouco sobre [`PWA`](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/). Além do mais, este seu requisito, me parece muito com um `SPA`. Talvez uma ferramenta que venha a lhe ajudar, seja o [`Quasar Framework`](http://quasar-framework.org), seja [`PWA`](https://medium.com/matheus-rossi/pwa-vue-js-quasar-ac97d775fcca) ou [`ElectronJS`](http://quasar-framework.org/guide/electron-preparation.html)

Comment: @Tobias, acessei o showcase do quasar, eles implementar uma descrição na url, e o conteudo é carregado dinamicamente com ajax, tornando possivel o voltar. Eu já havi visto algo assim, mas como fazer..seria só esse detalhe. E o codigo q vc colocou abaixo me parece resolver tbm, apenas não consegui testar ainda

Answer (score 1):

você terá que adicionar algum `state` ao `history`, você irá recuperar ele no evento `popstate`

o exemplo abaixo irá adicionar o valor do `input` como um `state` no `history`.
caso navegue, o valor do `input` será atualizado com o valor presente no `history`.

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var add = document.getElementById("add");
add.addEventListener("click", function () {
  history.pushState(text.value, document.title, "/");
})

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(evt){
  text.value = evt.state
});
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" />
<input id="add" type="button" value="Adicionar" />
```

O exemplo não funciona aqui no `SO`, mas pode ser visto no [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/f4ghjnsu/7/)

**EDIT**

Já que você precisa de mais jquery...

```js
var text = $("#text");
var add = $("#add");
add.on("click", function () {
  history.pushState(text.val(), document.title, "/");
})

$(window).on("popstate", function(evt){
  text.val(evt.state);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text" />
<input id="add" type="button" value="Adicionar" />
```

## `YOU MIGHT NOT NEED JQUERY`

Comment: Visualizei o fiddle, percebi que a cada adicionar, um novo item no historico foi adicionado. Agora como faço para resgatar esse valor adicionado e utilizar para que o voltar seja relacionada a tela anterior?

Comment: Você conseguiria traduzir aquele codigo para o formato jquery?

Comment: @Neo na navegação você deve adicionar informações ao `state` que identifique aquela pagina. quando o usuario vir a navegar, o evento popstate será executado e o respectivo `state`, então você deve recriar a pagina apartir dele.

Answer (score 1):

Já que você esta carregando estas páginas dinamicamente o correto seria usar a [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) e salvar este "novo estado".

Como você não postou nenhum código de como irá gerenciar as chamadas (`.load()`) este exemplo assume que:

- o "rooteamento" será disparado no evento `click`
- a "rota" será um valor no atributo `data-value=""` no botão
- um "contêiner" irá servir para mostrar o conteúdo carregado
- ao retornar ao estado padrão do histórico (null) o contêiner é limpo

---

**EXEMPLO**

```
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<button type="button" data-value="pagina1.html" class="navigate">Carregar pagina1.html</button>
<button type="button" data-value="pagina2.html" class="navigate">Carregar pagina2.html</button>
<button type="button" data-value="pagina3.html" class="navigate">Carregar pagina3.html</button>

<script src="path/to/jequery.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.navigate ').on('click', function() {
        let target = $(this).attr('data-value')
        $('#container').load(target, function() {
            history.pushState(target, "", "/")
        })
    })
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(evt) {
        if ( evt.state ) {
            $('#container').load(evt.state)
        } else {
            $('#container').html('')
        }
    }, false)
</script>
</body>
```

Nas páginas um simples `<h1>` indicando em qual página esta...você poderá navegar no histórico a "frente" e de "volta".

O estado inicial do histórico é `null`, ao chegar no estado inicial (caso de retornar) apenas exiba sua interface padrão.